# iPhone  - Update current view before pushing new ViewController on UITableViewCell selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` with a list of items. On selection of an item I'm navigating to a new view that displays the details of the selected item using:

```
DetailsVC *detailsView = [[DetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsView animated:YES];
```

Now, the details view is getting the data from the remote location so on slow connection it can take a few seconds. What I want to do is display an activity indicator over the selected row on selection.

The problem is the display of the added indicator gets delayed until the next view is ready to navigate to, which makes the indicator usless.

I've tried to add this indicator in those 2 events with the same effect:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Is there a way to add the indicator (or more general, modify the content of a `UITableViewCell`) in the moment of selection, before navigation occurs.

As a experiment I've also tried to pop up an alert view in the same two events which resulted in poping up the alert after navigation to the details view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's `[[DetailsVC alloc] init...]` that takes a few seconds, right? This problem is that any view changes you make don't fully take effect until returning all the way back to the runloop, so even if you setup the indicator before creating your object, it too is waiting for the init to finish to make itself visible. What you need to do is defer the creation of your `DetailsVC` until after the indicator is setup.

I might be a simpler change to use blocks but I can't recall the details of that off the top of my head (haven't used blocks much since code I've been writing lately has had to stay compatible with 3.x). But to use `performSelector` is easy too, take those 2 lines you first quoted in your question and put them into its own method, such as:

```
- (void)pushDetailsView {
  DetailsVC *detailsView = [[DetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsVC" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsView animated:YES];
}
```

And where you had those lines before, setup your indicator and then do this (a delay of 0 doesn't mean to called it immediately, but rather ASAP after returning all the way out of the current call stack):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pushDetailsView) withObject:nil withDelay:0]
```

Comment: Also there is this workaround that I've come across. If you place the time consuming operaton in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` instead of `- (void) viewDidLoad` of the `DetailsVC` the view will get pushed immediately and you will be able to display the activity indicator in that view instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `cell = [self rowForIndexPath:indexPath]` in one of your functions. and then add the indicator to cells subview

Comment: As an explanation: I don't have a problem with adding the indicator. The problem is making it appear sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. add the indicator when u select row and push new view when data came
   (simultaneously remove indicator at that time) or
2. Push new view, call web service to get corresponding cell data (in
   viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear) and display indicator simultaneously
   and when new data comes remove indicator

Comment: Yes, I want to do 1), the question is how. The data is being loaded by the details view.

Comment: set the corresponding detail view properties in table view when data came,